# Excel 2010 Array (CSE) Formula: How to remove a part of contiguous (adjacent) range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, cells, array, range

I would really appreciate help on the following question:

**Is there a way to write a formula that removes a segment from a contiguous range?**

For example, say there is a formula =COUNTIF((A1:A100),">1") and **I want to disregard A20:A40 for whatever reason.**

Basically I am looking for the most convenient way to either **1) Split a contiguous range into 2 parts without breaking the logic** or **2) Combine 2 non-adjacent ranges to create a contiguous range effect.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an array formula try

```
=SUM(IF(((A1:A100>1)*((ROW(A1:A100)<20)+(ROW(A1:A100)>40)))>0,1,0))
```

You can also do this CSE free with

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100>1)*((ROW(A1:A100)<20)+(ROW(A1:A100)>40)))
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Thank you so much!!!